# Inverse Z-transform with a complex root

Tags: z-transform

The z-transform of a signal is 
$$ X(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+z+1}$$
I attempted to solve for the the inverse z-transform by decomposing the denominator into complex roots, $\alpha$ and $\alpha^\ast$, to get

$$\frac{1}{z^2+z+1} = \frac{A}{z-\alpha}+\frac{B}{z-\alpha^\ast}=\frac{\frac{-i\sqrt{3}}{3}}{z-\alpha}+\frac{\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{3}}{z-\alpha^\ast}$$
for $$\alpha = e^{2\pi i /3}  \ \ \text{and}  \ \ \alpha^\ast = e^{-2\pi i /3}$$

And ultimately this leads to a long process of manipulating a series to relate it to the definition of the z-tranform. I was wondering if there was a faster or easier way to solve this problem, perhaps with a more direct series expansion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $(1-z)(1+z+z^2)=1-z^3$. (That's a trick worth noting whenever you're working with $1+z+z^2+\ldots z^n$.)

So $1/(z^2+z+1)$ is actually $(1-z)/(1-z^3)$.

$1/(1-z^3)$ is the sum of a geometric progression ie. $1+z^3+z^6+\ldots$.

So the final result is $1+z^3+z^6+\ldots-z(1+z^3+z^6+\ldots)$

So if we write $X(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ we have

$a_n=\cases{1&$n=0$ mod $3$\cr -1&$n=1$ mod $3$\cr0&$n=2$ mod 3}$

It's a surprisingly simple result!

Comment: Good point. I should have thought of that. You can obtain the same result with my method by recognizing that $\alpha$ and $\alpha^*$ are both 3rd roots of unity. Very slick.

Comment: Combining our answers gives an interesting way to write $(1,-1,0,1,-1,0,\ldots)$. Occasionally these things are useful when people want to write sequences like that without using conditional expressions.

Answer (score 2):

What you may do next is write $$\frac{A}{z-\alpha} + \frac{B}{z-\alpha^*} = \frac{A}{-\alpha}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{\alpha}} + \frac{B}{-\alpha^*}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{\alpha^*}} = \frac{A}{-\alpha}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{\alpha^n} z^n \right) + \frac{B}{-\alpha^*}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{\alpha^{*n}} z^n \right)$$

$$= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[ \frac{A}{-\alpha}\left( \frac{1}{\alpha^n} \right) +\frac{B}{-\alpha^*} \left( \frac{1}{\alpha^{*n}}\right)\right]z^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n z^n$$

Thus $$x_n = \left[ \frac{A}{-\alpha}\left( \frac{1}{\alpha^n} \right) +\frac{B}{-\alpha^*} \left( \frac{1}{\alpha^{*n}}\right)\right]$$

Comment: Actually, I suppose my assumption was that you wanted an explicit formula for $x_n$... here it is if you wanted it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did the same thing but with the actual values which made things more tedious. The z-transform that I am referring to is defined by $z^{-n}$ which means that the final answer needs to be multiplied by $-u[-n]$, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Is there another signal that has the same transform but with $u[n-1]$ and of course a different ROC? Because looking at examples there are multiple signals for a single transform but with different ROC. I was wondering how one can find the others?

Comment: You might shift the signal by multiplying by $z^{N}$. The signal itself will be a delayed version of the original. Other than that, I am not sure. Honestly, most of my intuition comes from using generating functions in combinatorics.